# Removing properties with null values

Tags: azure, json.net, azure-cosmosdb

In my DocumentDb documents, I don't want to include properties with NULL values. For example, I have the following POCO class.

```
public class Person
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName="id")]
   public int PersonId {get; set;}

   [JsonProperty(PropertyName="firstName")]
   public string FirstName {get; set;}

   [JsonProperty(PropertyName="middleName")]
   public string MiddleName {get; set;}

   [JsonProperty(PropertyName="lastName")]
   public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

Some people don't have middle names and when I save a person's document in my collection, I don't want the middle name to be included. Currently, a person without a middle name is saved as:

```
{
   "id": 1234,
   "firstName": "John",
   "middleName": null,
   "lastName": "Smith"
}
```

Is this normal behavior? If not, how do I **NOT** include the middle name property with a NULL value in my document?

P.S. All serialization/deserialization is handled by JSON.NET

Comment: Could you handle it if the property was set to an empty `String`, i.e `""`

Answer (score 8):

You can do that when you initialize the Cosmos Client, there's a serialization option which is similar to the JSON.Net.

```cs
CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(yourConnectionString, new CosmosClientOptions()
                {
                    SerializerOptions = new CosmosSerializationOptions()
                    {
                        IgnoreNullValues = true,
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the answer. Looks like I can tell JSON.NET to ignore properties with NULL values using

```
NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
```

Here's the documentation:
http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size